# Pandas converting all data to NaN after adding column values

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I'm trying to add column headers to the following set of data. As per specifications of the project, I cannot simply modify the file to add those headers manually.

Sample of the data that I'm working with:

```
38.049133   0.224026 0.05398  -19.11 -20.03
38.352526   0.212491 0.05378  -18.35 -19.19
38.363598   0.210654 0.05401  -20.11 -20.89
54.936819   0.216794 0.20114  -20.94 -21.88
54.534881   0.578615 0.12887  -19.75 -20.66
54.743075   0.508774 0.18331  -20.54 -21.53
54.867240   0.562636 0.13956  -19.95 -20.85
54.856908   0.544031 0.13938  -20.14 -21.03
54.977748   0.501912 0.13923  -20.27 -21.01
54.992762   0.460376 0.12723  -20.24 -20.83
```

I've created an array of 5 strings to act as the headers of each of the columns within this DataFrame. Using the designated header does select only that column (i.e. `print(df['z'])` does only print that one column (supposedly) but all of the data in the DataFrame, that displays just fine (i.e. shows the above sample lines exactly and detects the columns properly) when I do not specify columns, suddenly becomes "NaN" when I specify column titles from the array of strings.

Sample of my code:

```
... imports and whatnot not shown

dataColumns = ['RA', 'DEC', 'z', 'M(g)', 'M(r)']
dataFile = pd.read_csv(data = 'file_name', delim_whitespace = True)
df = pd.DataFrame(data = dataFile, columns = dataColumns)

print(df)
```

Sample output of the above code (it is supposed to display exactly the sample data above but with added column headers):

```
RA   DEC z  M(g) M(r)
NaN   NaN NaN  NaN NaN
NaN   NaN NaN  NaN NaN
NaN   NaN NaN  NaN NaN
NaN   NaN NaN  NaN NaN
NaN   NaN NaN  NaN NaN
NaN   NaN NaN  NaN NaN
NaN   NaN NaN  NaN NaN
NaN   NaN NaN  NaN NaN
NaN   NaN NaN  NaN NaN
NaN   NaN NaN  NaN NaN
```

Why is it that, without specifying the 'columns' parameter for DataFrame, the data will properly print wheras after specifying the parameter, everything displays as NaN?

Any help would be appreciated!

-- paanvaannd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your problem, use this line instead:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file_name', header=None, names=dataColumns)
```

`pd.read_csv` returns a DataFrame, so the above line should handle the entirety of the import (i.e. calling `pd.DataFrame` on the result of `pd.read_csv` is superfluous). `header=None` indicates that pandas shouldn't interpret the first line of the CSV as headers, and then `names=...` allows you to specify the column names you'd like to use. `delim_whitespace` shouldn't be used, since commas, not whitespace, appears to be the delimiter in your data ('comma' is the 'c' in 'csv', after all). In fact, without testing your data, I'd say the use of `delim_whitespace` is the most likely culprit behind the NaN values.

Comment: You're welcome! Please accept this answer if it's the one you used :)

Comment: Accepted :+) As for my question for @James posed in the comment to their response: is there any reason for choosing to use `df.columns` over specifying the `names` parameter?

Comment: P.S. the delimiter is actually whitespace in the data file, there are no commas there. Should I be using another Pandas function to read in the datafile instead? It's working fine using `pd.read_csv` though it's not a CSV file (it's just plaintext with tab separation, I think) after setting `delim_whitespace` to 'True' and not reading a data frame into a data frame haha!

Comment: `df.columns` vs. `names` is really just a matter of preference; there might be some cases where `df.columns` is more readable (for instance, if a number of other arguments are being passed to `read_csv`, or if the list of column names is long). I personally always would use `names`, if possible.

Comment: No, `read_csv` should be fine -- it's actually very capable of inferring data structure from a variety of formats. I often try letting `read_csv` parse the data once before manually specifying a delimiter, unless I know for sure it will cause problems. `read_csv` is a specialized version of `read_table`, which can be adapted to read an even broader range of formats -- take a look at the documentation and you'll see :) http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a dataframe that you created when you used `.read_csv` to a the dataframe constructor `pd.DataFrame`.  I am actually surprised it didn't throw an error.

Try this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(data = 'file_name', delim_whitespace = True)
df.columns = dataColumns
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance! That makes sense. One correction to your suggested code, though: `read_csv` does not accept a 'data' parameter, it's just `df = pd.read_csv('file_name', delim_whitespace = True)`. I'm also using @cmaher's more succinct version of specifying 'names' instead of adding the columns in a separate line. This is just stylistic and achieves the same result, right? Is there a reason one would split the command over specifying it when calling the function?